# mlflow.exceptions.MlflowException: Could not find a registered artifact repository

Tags: python, mlflow

I have mlflow experiment on remote server.

I user pytorch_lightning for creating experiment

```
from pytorch_lightning.loggers import MLFlowLogger
 logger = MLFlowLogger(
    experiment_name=EXPERIMENT_NAME,
    tracking_uri=MLFLOW_TRACKING_URI,
    run_name=args.prefix
)
```

I can successfully see at mlflow UI that my experiment and run created.
I successfully log log_hyperparams

```
logger.log_hyperparams({"run_id": self.logger.run_id})
```

But when i try to log dict

```
    logger.experiment.log_dict(mlf_logger.run_id, {1:1 , 2:2}, 'test.json')
```

I have following error

```
mlflow.exceptions.MlflowException: Could not find a registered artifact repository for: mlflow-artifacts:/7/d736955490f6444b916d5881b067aac1/artifacts. Currently registered schemes are: ['', 'file', 's3', 'gs', 'wasbs', 'ftp', 'sftp', 'dbfs', 'hdfs', 'viewfs', 'runs', 'models']
```

Answer (score -1):

You should upgrade your mlflow version & try it again.